# Python - Reading dictionaries' values inside dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

quick problem here. I have a dictionary like this (with more entries):

```
champlist = {
      "Aatrox": {
         "id": 266,
         "title": "the Darkin Blade",
         "name": "Aatrox",
         "key": "Aatrox"
      },
      "Thresh": {
         "id": 412,
         "title": "the Chain Warden",
         "name": "Thresh",
         "key": "Thresh"
      }
}
```

And i like to read all the id's. I'm trying like this

```
for champ in champlist:
   print(champ['id'])
```

But it says:

`print(champ['id'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

It doesn't pick each "champ" as a dictionary, but as a string, any help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate a dictionary like that. Try to iterate the values instead:

```
for champ in champlist.values():
    print(champ['id'])
```

For completeness, just keys:

```
for key in champlist.keys():
    print(key)
```

or if you need key value combo:

```
for key, val in champlist.items():
    print('%s - %s', key, val)
```

There are also identical `itervalues`, `iterkeys`, and `iteritems` methods that return iterators instead of lists (better for large objs)

Comment: No prob, pretty sure this has hit every new Python dev at one point or another

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Variable = champlist['Thresh']['id']
```

To iterate: use the `iterkeys()`, `itervalues()`, or `iteritems()` methods of the dictionaries.

Look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) fore more info. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
print [v['id'] for (k, v) in champlist.iteritems()]
```